# Prepending Masonry Items from a custom javascript module

Tags: javascript, jquery, masonry

I have a div with the class '.masonry-processed' that is my Masonry container. On page load, this loads all the items and formats them correctly.

I also have a list of hidden items at the bottom, in a separate container. I want to pull some items out of this container and prepend them to the Masonry grid. Each item as an attribute of data-date. If the date is within two weeks of today, then this item should be prepended.

I have a custom Javascript module that I am trying to add the prepend function to.

The module performs the logic of whether the event should prepended, and then sends the date of the event that should be prepended to this function:

```
stampDates: function(dataDate){
    // adds the masonry item class to the object
    eventItem = jQuery(this.eventItem).attr('data-date', dataDate).addClass('masonry-item');

    allEvents = this.prependEvents;
    // add the current item to the events array
    allEvents.push(eventItem);
    // prepend the events to the grid
    jQuery('.masonry-processed').prepend(this.prependEvents);
    // trigger the masonry layout
    jQuery('.masonry-processed').masonry('prepended', this.prependEvents);
}
```

The problem is that nothing happens. If I open my console and enter `$('.masonry-processed').prepend(this.prependEvents);`, the events will be prepended, but the layout never reorganizes. How do I get the elements to prepend in this function, and how do I get the layout to reformat?

Comment: create a jsfiddle. it looks like it should work.